# accessing user generated control via findControl method

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a jQuery function that lets users add textboxes inside a "div" with an id of "textBoxContainer".

So the html would look like this:

```
<div id="textBoxContainer">
    <table>
        <tr>
           <td><input type="text" name="fname" value="John"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
           <td><input type="text" name="lname" value="Smith"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
           <td><input type="text" name="city" value="New York City"></td>
        </tr>  
    </table>
</div>
```

I'm trying to access these textboxes via find control like this, but it is not working. It's always returning a null reference error.

Does anyone know why it's failing?  Thanks

```
    Dim textBoxContainer As HtmlGenericControl = CType(Page.FindControl("textBoxContainer"), HtmlGenericControl)


    For Each control As HtmlInputText In textBoxContainer.Controls.Cast(Of HtmlInputText)()
        If TypeOf control Is HtmlInputText Then
            'do something
            Response.Write(control.Value)
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously inputs generated on the clientside will not be visible on the serverside, because those are not regenerated during postback lifecycle, so it is not your way to do that.

If you really need this dynamic input generation and want to read those values on the serverside then AJAX is your solution. You should create those inputs during AJAX callbacks on the serverside and you will be able to read the values during following round trips, but with this approach performance may get significantly slower.

EDIT:
What I mean here is if you create inputs on the clientside with jquery then on the serverside you will have problems reading the values. My suggestion was... Say you create inputs with jquery on some button click. So instead of that on this button click you can make an AJAX call to the server (by just placing your inputs container and button inside an Update Panel) and then during AJAX callback you can create those inputs on the SERVERSIDE by accessing your textboxContainer which should be marked as runat=server then and adding children via textboxContainer.Controls.Add(children). After that modified HTML will be returned back to client and during next postback when you actually post your data you will be able to find your controls by FindControl method.

Another idea I just figured out: maybe it is possible for you to hidden field and serialize all your values into the value of this input field, then you can deserialize the values on the serverside and hence bypass FindControl method (you will only need access hidden field).

Comment: But why?  If it's on the page, and the page is processed server side, why can't you find the controls on the page with findControl?  Thanks

Comment: FindControl method looks for children controls on the serverside. During postback you don't post all your html to the server but only values of those inputs via post data. Server has no idea if those inputs should be in the table or maybe div or any other html element. Server starts with the markup configured in aspx (or ascx) file and then only modifies it with server events (for example automatically changing values of the inputs by post data), but server doesn't add those inputs, unless you do that manually in the code-behind. I hope my explanation is clear.Let me know if you have questions

Comment: Thanks Ihor, so the only way to access controls created with jQuery is to use jQuery/ajax?

Comment: Actually you didn't fully understand what I meant. I will make a post update soon.